# OData - Handling Structural Changes

Tags: c#, architecture, schema, changes

Working with the Success Factors OData API and encountering issues whenever the schema is modified.

For example this morning my code broke because a new column was added to provide new functionality. My code obviously wasn't using the new column but an exception was raised because it encountered an unexpected column.

How can I handle this gracefully once my code is in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Simple.OData.Client to solve the problem as it's loosely coupled and has worked well.